# Navigator this.props.navigator.pop is not working, React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on react native application.

In that I implemented react native gifted messenger for chat.

My Issue is:

1. I am in background and i got a push notifications when user send the messages. suppose I got 10 messages.
2. After clicking on the notification I am redirecting to chat page in that i have a back button when clicking on that I wrote:

   `this.props.navigator.pop();`
3. But when I click on that my screen is not poping and not going to back screen.

Here is the code when i get a notification:

```
    onNotification:(notification)=>{
      console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:',notification);
      if(this.state.appstate =='background'){

          this.props.navigator.push({
          component:Chat,
          passProps:{fromUserId:userId,toUserId:oponentUserId}
        })

        }
    }
```

What can be done to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that navigator.push is being executed?

Comment: Yes It is getting pushed I am getting the chat screen but I think It is being pushed multiple times

Comment: Here When I get a notification in background, the onNotification() method is called when notification arrives and it is called again when I Click on the notification resulting in pushing to chat screen twice.

Comment: just to be sure, did you watch 'this.state.appstate' to see what it is holding on? I mean: console.log( 'this.state.appstate:',this.state.appstate);
I was looking for in internet, and your code seems to be well-done, sadly, i cant test it now

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca  Yes it prints as background when app is in background and active when it is in foreground. But the onNotification is called twice when getting a notification and when clicking on the notification. This issue is only in android.